# How can I set up two navigation properties of the same type in Entity Framework without use Fluent API

Tags: ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

i'm trying create DB using codefirst. i want to create two ForeingKey from same table. But when i set up two navigation properties of the same type, get error like :

> The foreign key name 'FollowedUser' was not found on the dependent type Models.UserUserWatchListItem'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

```
public class UserUserWatchListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    [Key,ForeignKey("FollowedUser")]
    public virtual User FollowedUser { get; set; }
    public int FollowedUserId { get; set; }

    [Key,ForeignKey("FolloweeUser")]
    public int FolloweeUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User FolloweeUser { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
public class UserUserWatchListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    public int FollowedUserId { get; set; }


    public int FolloweeUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FollowedUser")]
    [InverseProperty("FollowedUsers")]
    public virtual User FollowedUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FolloweeUser")]
    [InverseProperty("FolloweeUsers")]
    public virtual User FolloweeUser { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    ...

    [InverseProperty("FollowedUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserUserWatchListItem> FollowedUsers { get; set; }   

    [InverseProperty("FolloweeUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserUserWatchListItem> FolloweeUsers { get; set; }   

}
```